# requesting assistance with a syntax error in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm not very savy with scripts in google sheets, and trying to implement a script that would remove accented characters from a field, but I get a syntax error on this line of code:

const basePropertyOf = (object) => (key) => object[key];

Can someone help me detect the error?

I am using the script as explained on this website: https://www.labnol.org/replace-accented-characters-210709

Thanks for the help.

I havent tried anything since I am unfamiliar with any options to try.

Comment: I copied the script from labnol as is and it works for me.  I used the test data they provide on their web page.

Comment: In your situation, V8 runtime has already been enabled in your script editor?